# CoordinatorLayout adds extra space to BottomSheet in fullscreen Dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I'm working on an aplication targetting API 22.

I'm trying to add a `BottomSheet` at the bottom of a view, displayed in a fullscreen `AlertDialog`.

Unfortunately, `CoordinatorLayout` seems to add extra space at the bottom of the view.

However, this extra space is not added when this layout is set as `contentView` of an `Activity`

See the difference in these screenshots :

[image: Difference between in-activity and in Dialog]

I can't undestand why this layout is displayed correctly as an activity contentView, and not in a fullscreen Dialog.

You can find below the code producing these result, based on a newly created Android app from Android Studio wizard :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/top_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:title="[Title]">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- [...] --> 

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="148dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="BottomSheet Header" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/payment_buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:text="TEST 1" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:text="TEST 2" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="TEST 3" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
                android:text="TEST 4" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the MainActivity from which the AlertDialog is built and shown :

```kotlin
package com.axample.bottomsheetondialog

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(app_bar)

        bs_dialog.setOnClickListener {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppTheme_FullscreenDialog)
                .setView(R.layout.view_with_bottomsheet)
                .create()
                .show()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the simple-doing-nothing Activity where the problem do not occur

```kotlin
package fr.izypay.bottomsheetondialog

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.view_with_bottomsheet.*

class BottomsheetActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.view_with_bottomsheet)
        setSupportActionBar(top_app_bar)

        top_app_bar.title = "Bottomsheet in an activity"
    }

}
```

And finally, this is the Theme used for fullscreen-ness (see AppTheme.FullscreenDialog)

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.FullscreenDialog" parent="AppTheme">

        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I really need this kind of layout to achieve a scrollable list (here with numbers) an an always-on-top growing toolbar at the bottom (the BottomSheet).

I know it can be achieved by some other way, but it sounds to me as a bug.

Does anyone know a solution for this to work ?

Comment: Please don't link to relevant code off-site. You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: OK, removed off-site part.

Comment: You kinda missed the [mcve] part. That said, don't use an `AlertDialog` for this. Use a plain `Dialog` instead.

Comment: I added Kotlin Activity definitions for clarity.
For the second part of your comment, we use AlertDialog as stated here (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs):

```The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses : 
AlertDialog
...
```

Comment: That's just bad advice to be stating as a generality. I don't know why they'd say that. It's perfectly fine to use `Dialog` directly, especially when you don't need or want any of the inherent internal structure that the framework subclasses have. `AlertDialog` is specialized toward what you might call "standard" dialogs; i.e., those with titles, brief messages, yes/no/cancel buttons, etc. What you're trying to do does not fit that style, so there's really no point in using `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain that's your whole problem, anyway. There's a support library class that does basically what you're doing – fullscreen dialog with a bottom sheet – and it uses `Dialog` directly, with no gaps anywhere.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Switched to Dialog and everithing is as expected now.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) in this question's comments, I had to avoid using `AlertDialog.Builder`, and use `Dialog` instead, built by ourselves.

In `MainActivity`, I had to replace

```kotlin
AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppTheme_FullscreenDialog)
    .setView(R.layout.view_with_bottomsheet)
    .create()
    .show()
```

by

```kotlin
Dialog(this, R.style.AppTheme_FullscreenDialog).also {
    it.setContentView(R.layout.view_with_bottomsheet)
    it.show()
}
```

and the layout now behaves as expected.